# Binding DataTable with ListBox

Tags: c#

I am experimenting and learning windows forms application and I am unable to figure out the binding construct.
As per the MSDN documentation:- **You can specify an instance of any of the following classes for the data source:**

**DataSet**

**DataTable**

**DataView**

**DataViewManager**

**BindingSource**

So, I have  a simple code to understand this construct.

I have have initialized a simple windows form with listbox listBox1 and DataTable data_table.

```
 static DataTable data_table = new DataTable("ParentTable");  
DataColumn column;
                DataRow row;
                column = new DataColumn();
                column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
                column.ColumnName = "id";
                column.ReadOnly = false;
                column.Unique = true;
                // Add the Column to the DataColumnCollection.
                data_table.Columns.Add(column);
                for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
                {
                    row = data_table.NewRow();
                    row["id"] = i;

                    data_table.Rows.Add(row);
                }
```

can directly bind to DataSource by.

```
listBox1.DataSource=new BindingSource(data_table , null);
listBox1.ValueMemeber="id";
```

But when I use the following

```
 Binding myBinding = new Binding("DataSource", data_table, "id");

 form_m.listBox1.DataBindings.Add(myBinding);
```

I get exception

> System.ArgumentException: Complex DataBinding accepts as a data source
>   either an IList or an IListSource

I will really appreciate if someone can help me with this.

Comment: Note that the [tagging help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) explicitly states: _"Avoid inserting tags into titles in any of the following formats:"_ ... _"[tag]: [question title]"_

Comment: If it really Winforms, `BindingSource` is probably what you want to use - or nothing at all because a `DataTable` will work

Answer (score 1):

You are using constructor overload with three arguments [Binding(String, Object, String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.binding.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_Binding__ctor_System_String_System_Object_System_String_)
Where parameters are
**propertyName**
 - The name of the control property to bind.
 - `DataSource` in your case

**dataSource**
 - An Object that represents the data source.
 - This is a main datasource, notice it is not a datasource which will be bounded to `List.Box.DataSource`

**dataMember**
 - The property or list to bind to.
 - This is a name of the property in the main datasource, which value will be bound to the control's `DataSource`. This value should be an IList or an IListSource

You can set `ListBox.DataSource` without any extra binding

```
listBox.DataSource = myDataTable;
```

Check the link: [Windows Forms Data Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/windows-forms-data-binding)
There are should be enough information about how you can use data binding and if you go through examples you will get pretty good picture of how you can use data binding in for your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am still unable to find a way to use Binding construct. I know can use BindingSource, But, I would like to learn how this Binding construct functions. Also, I am interested in using the DataSourceUpdateMode

Comment: @user2288650, check the link I added to the answer.

Comment: Thanks – Fabio , I have read the docs and I can get the binding to work on Textbox no problem. It's just the listbox which is not working,

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any extra binding.
You can assign **List, Array, Tables** to the **DataSource** and also provide **DisplayMember** and **ValueMember** while you use List of object or table as **DataSource** if you use single dimension array then you don't need to provide **DisplayMember** and **ValueMember**.

```
listbox1.DataSource = data_table; 
listbox1.ValueMember = "id"; 
listbox1.DisplayMember = "id";
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am just trying to understand how this Binding constructor works